# Check if user had filled questionnaire before with Django

Tags: python, django, if-statement, exists

I'm working on a questionnaire and I made a page where user have a list of which questionnaires to fill and which did he filled before but I have stucked.
I like to check if the user filled a form/questionnaire before and if he didn't show him the questionnaire link.
My solutions doesn't work because it checks the db just if the user filled the questionnaire but if he did not (no row for him in the db) it shows a blank cell in my table.
(I don't know if exists query could be a solution but I can't made it work)

**main.html**

```html
    {% for i in oke_vezetoi %}
      {% if i.vezetoi_ok == True %}
          <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-info"> <a href="{% url 'stressz:vezetoi_item' %}">Kitöltöm</a></button>      
          <td><i class="fas fa-running fa-2x text-dark"></i></td>
      {% else %}
          <td class="text-success text-uppercase">Kitöltötted</button>      
          <td><i class="fas fa-check fa-2x text-success"></i></td>     
      {% endif %}  
    {% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```py
def main(request):
    
    oke_vezetoi = Vezetoi.objects.filter(user_name=request.user)
    oke_stressz = Stressz_teszt.objects.filter(user_name=request.user)

    context = {
        'oke_vezetoi': oke_vezetoi,
        'oke_stressz': oke_stressz,
    }
    return render(request, 'stressz/main.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```py
class Vezetoi(models.Model):
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)

    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    vezetoi_v01 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v02 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v03 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v04 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v05 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v06 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v07 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v08 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v09 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v10 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v11 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_v12 = models.IntegerField(  null=True)
    vezetoi_ok = models.BooleanField()
```

**forms.py**

```py
class VezetoiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vezetoi
        fields = ['vezetoi_v01', 'vezetoi_v02', 'vezetoi_v03', 'vezetoi_v04', 'vezetoi_v05', 'vezetoi_v06', 'vezetoi_v07', 'vezetoi_v08', 'vezetoi_v09', 'vezetoi_v10', 'vezetoi_v11', 'vezetoi_v12', 'vezetoi_ok' ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting your question correctly, but it seems like there are a few things that you could optimise.

1. It sounds like there should only be one entry per user in the `Vezetoi` model.

If this is true, you should enforce `ForeignKey(unique=True)`, and you don't need a for loop and you can use `Vezetoi.objects.get()` in your `views.py`

If this is not true, and there are multiple `Vezetoi` integers per user, you might want to have one `Vezetoi` object for each integer.

2. If the user hasn't submitted a questionnaire, then the `Vezetoi` model object will not exist.

- Since the object doesn't exist, it won't appear in the `oke_vezetoi` queryset, so the object attribute `i.vezetoi_ok` will not be found in your loop (this is why your table row is blank).
- Assuming the field `vezetoi_ok` is only intended to check for the existence of the questionnaire, it can only ever be True, so you can remove it from the model definition.

If these are not true, I'll need to amend the answer and I'll ask you to provide more information about what these models are tracking, the content of the `Stressz_teszt` model and `urls.py` as well as how the `VezetoiForm` is implemented.

So in the case that I've described, I'd do it like this with a class based view and the `get_context_data` method.

**models.py**

```
class Vezetoi(models.Model):

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_name)

    user_name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, unique=True)
    vezetoi_v01 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    ...
    # vezetoi_ok = models.BooleanField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class VezetoiForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vezetoi
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class MainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'main.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context['oke_vezetoi'] = Vezetoi.objects.get(user_name=request.user)
        context['oke_stressz'] = Stressz_teszt.objects.get(user_name=request.user)
        return context
```

**main.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% if oke_vezetoi %}
    {# do not display link #}
{% else %}
    {# display link #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you James! I'll try it tomorrow.